# How to enable logging in Hybris 6.0 for all class files?

Tags: logging, sap-commerce-cloud

I migrated my Hybris application from 5.7 to 6.0. Everything is working fine apart from the Logging architecture.

Earlier with 5.7, Logging used to work for all the class files. However, with the newer version of Hybris ( 6.0 ), it doesnt seem to work for those files.

I went through a few blogs and came to know that this is an architecture change in Hyris with 6.0 release.

Is there anyway I can enable logging for all the class files in 6.0 as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this page : https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/42d818c7bac44eed9ab01757472b9dbc.html

Since Hybris V6 they have migrated to *log4j2* so to declare a new logger you need to use for the package *com.hybhub.hybhubaddon* with *debug* log level :

```
log4j2.logger.hybhub.name=com.hybhub.hybhubaddon
log4j2.logger.hybhub.level = debug
log4j2.logger.hybhub.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

After this from the HMC you would be able to see the package com.hybhub.hybhubaddon and change directly its log level.

Comment: Benoit, I didnt get you properly. The configuration you mentioned, I understood that. But what you wrote after that. I dont want to change the log levels for all the classes. My class files are not visible in the Logging section of HAC. Unless they are available, I wont be able to change their logging levels. I hope I was able to make it clear.